# Dictionary Error

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

Here am trying to read data from excel and map the two columns in to an dictionary.
The result is only single key & value when i print it.
please let me know the procedure. .?

```
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.load_workbook('c:/users/c_thv/desktop/tax.xlsx')
sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('Thilip')
cell = sheet.cell(row=2,column = 4)
i = 2
x = []
y = []
while i < 10:
   keys = sheet.cell(row=i,column = 4)
   values = sheet.cell(row = i,column = 5)
   x.append(keys.value)
   y.append(values.value)
   i +=1
mydict = {key:value for key, value in zip(x,y)}
print mydict
```

Out put is :
`TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration`

Comment: Use pdb/debug printing to see the values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I'm Sorry, i Cannot understand the pdb structure as it shows unexpected EOF when i type `While i < 10:`
Please help.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean by "pdb". I mean [the python debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html?highlight=pdb), specifically, its interactive mode.

Comment: Yes,the same. . It shows the 'Unexpected EOF' on `While i < 10:` of my above code. .

Comment: Must be a syntax error then - probably, an indentation issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for` loop instead of `while` and assign items directly to your dictionary within it.

It looks like you want values from the "D" column to be your keys and from "E" to be values. Something like the following should work:

```
mydict = {}
for row in range(2, 10):
    key = sheet.cell(row, 4).value
    value = sheet.cell(row, 5).value
    mydict[key] = value
```